# Typescript scoped variable with generated javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm just learning typescript and following an online course.  I've hit a bit of a snag immediately and must be a vscode setting or something?

When I compile app.ts it generates the app.js but immediately I get a typescript error because the person variable is conflicting with the person variable in the app.js which was just generated.  **The error is "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable".**

Can someone tell me how to avoid this?

[image: app.ts]

[image: app.js]

Comment: It looks like you have TypeScript configured to treat your JS output directory as an input directory. Are they the same? If you post your `tsconfig.json` and folder structure, it'd be easier to help configure TypeScript not to treat its output as additional input.

Comment: Yes - ok.  I didnt have one but nor did the tutorial.  I added one and it fixed the issue.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved in the comments:

In absence of a `tsconfig.json` file, TypeScript (built into Visual Studio Code) treated your JS output directory as an input directory. The problem was solved by creating the file; if the file existed, it would require configuring TypeScript not to treat its output as additional input via `includes`, `excludes`, or `files` configurations (or by setting an `outFile` or `outDir`).